# Find local files with Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, local

I want to find the games that the current user plays.
For example, if you load the website, you will receive a popup with 'Add Counter Strike to my Games'?

Is there a way to search in the users C:/ drive for specific names via Javascript? Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I would not like you to search in my file-system!

Comment: Unless you happen to exploit a browser security issue this is impossible using JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to let the user select a file in this instance using a form. It would be terribly insecure to allow front end code access to the filesystem.

You could potentially achieve something with social media integration. Many games have social media integration, and you could potentially traverse a users likes in order to find games that match games in your database?

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript, it's impossible to browse local files.

It is a security protection of the most web-browsers.